# Why is this question still closed?

Tags: discussion, closing

Why is [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387428/how-do-i-make-a-custom-potion-with-bedrock-edition-addons) still closed? It's not a duplicate and I've voted to reopen several times. I don't see any argument for why they are duplicates and no one has even provided one either. They are separate questions, one for commands and one for addons.

Comment: So for the technical "why", according to the timeline, this question received 4 reopen votes that have all expired. Additionally, in review, it received 2 reopen and 3 leave closed reviews. You should be able to resubmit your expired reopen vote I believe.

Comment: @Unionhawk that can happen? I didn't know they can expire.

Comment: Yes, [close and reopen votes age away after 14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting) but can be recast

Answer (score 2):

The question you have linked to is not a duplicate. It clearly wishes to use a different method than the current duplicate target describes.

However, *before* you click the reopen button, we have to consider that the question *may* be off-topic for a different reason. You see, game and mod development is off-topic also, so we need to gain a firm stance on whether MCBE add-ons are considered mods. If we *do* consider them mods, it will end up closed as off-topic anyways, and the guidelines say not to reopen a question just because the close reason is incorrect.

Let's all save our reopen votes until the [matter is settled](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15948/250180).